# Groovy-Eclipse compilation fails with NullPointerException in STS-3.3

Tags: groovy-eclipse

Following error is encountered while importing the reactor project (https://github.com/reactor/reactor) in STS 3.3.0:

- **Description:** Internal compiler error: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$6.call(CompilationUnit.java:863)
- **Resource:** ClosureReduce.groovy
- **Path:** /reactor-groovy/src/main/groovy/reactor/groovy/support
- **Location:** line 0
- **Type:** Java Problem

The version of Groovy-Eclipse being used is 2.9.0.xx-20130828-1400-e43-RELEASE.

The detailed stacktrace in Eclipse's workspace .log file is below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$6.call(CompilationUnit.java:863)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1200)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:631)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:609)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:586)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:565)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.StaticTypeCheckingSupport.evaluateExpression(StaticTypeCheckingSupport.java:1500)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.visitMethodCallArguments(StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.java:1852)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.visitMethodCallExpression(StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.java:2162)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.sc.StaticCompilationVisitor.visitMethodCallExpression(StaticCompilationVisitor.java:220)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitExpressionStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:236)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:37)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:103)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:114)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.visitConstructorOrMethod(StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.java:1374)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.startMethodInference(StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.java:1649)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.visitMethod(StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.java:1622)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.sc.StaticCompilationVisitor.visitMethod(StaticCompilationVisitor.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.sc.StaticCompileTransformation.visit(StaticCompileTransformation.java:72)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor.visitClass(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:146)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor$2.call(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1200)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:631)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:609)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:586)
    at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.internal.compiler.ast.GroovyCompilationUnitDeclaration.processToPhase(GroovyCompilationUnitDeclaration.java:184)
    at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.internal.compiler.ast.GroovyCompilationUnitDeclaration.generateCode(GroovyCompilationUnitDeclaration.java:1632)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnitResolver.resolve(CompilationUnitResolver.java:1233)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnitResolver.resolve(CompilationUnitResolver.java:712)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.internalCreateAST(ASTParser.java:1181)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.createAST(ASTParser.java:807)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ASTProvider$1.run(ASTProvider.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ASTProvider.createAST(ASTProvider.java:537)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ASTProvider.getAST(ASTProvider.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.SharedASTProvider.getAST(SharedASTProvider.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.SelectionListenerWithASTManager$PartListenerGroup.calculateASTandInform(SelectionListenerWithASTManager.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.SelectionListenerWithASTManager$PartListenerGroup$3.run(SelectionListenerWithASTManager.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```